# What is the filter size for Nikon D5100 with 18-55mm lens kit?

Tags: filters

What is the filter size for Nikon D5100 with 18-55mm lens kit?

Is it 52mm or 58mm?

Comment: Don't forget to read the manual of your camera. Most of the technical questions are answered in there ;)

Comment: @Heyfara - in this particular case, it would be reading the manual of the lens, not the camera.  The camera has nothing to do with filter size.  The lens is all that matters.

Comment: My bad. I thought the manual coming with a kit would talk about the lens too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it comes with either Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR or Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G ED II. According to Nikon's homepage they both have 52 mm filter thread.

[Here are a list of their zoom lenses](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/list.htm#zoom)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's 52mm. Have you got the camera and lens? If you look on the lens it will have a little symbol like this `⌀`, which will be followed by the screw thread size

Comment: Because this sign is often (enough) used in photography context, you can easily search for special characters from the [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2300/index.htm) site, and then copy-paste them anywhere (scroll down to "java data" for this).

Answer (score 1):

52mm will fit the Nikon 18-55 lens.

Comment: Why that particular link?  That's hardly a complete or full list of filters.  It feels a little link spammy to me as it doesn't add to the answer.